# Predicted probability values in GAM

Tags: r, gam

I have a GAM model

```
dat <- mgcv::gamSim(1,n=400,dist="binary",scale=2)
adjY <- gam(y~ s(x0)+s(x1),family=binomial(link="logit"),data=dat)
```

What would be the best way to get values of adjY for different values of X1.

I need to plot the odds ratio for different values of X1 . So if I can get adjY for different values of X1 and X1 = 0 , that will get me the odds ratio.

Any help to plot odds ratio with different X1 is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the `predict()` function? If you'd like us to provide the solution then you'll also need to provide a copy of the `dat` object.

Comment: I tried the predict() function but kinda got lost to find the adjY for X1=0. I added the dat object to the oderset.

Comment: Couple additional questions. 1. Is `gamSim` coming from the `mgcv` package? 2. When I run `gamSim` my `y` variable looks to be continuous but you're choosing a binomial link function which requires 0's and 1's. Do you mean to be using a logit model? Is `gamSim` providing you with the correct data?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to fix x0 = 0, and then vary x1. So,

```
predict(adjY, newdata = data.frame(x0 = 0, x1 = seq(0, 1, 0.1)))
```

Gives:

```
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
-1.7053449 -1.6085191 -1.5247794 -1.0849344 -0.4963113 -0.3463019 -0.1055901 
         8          9         10         11 
 0.7804438  2.1509790  3.7307655  5.3374277
```

These are the log-odds.  If you want the probabilities, use the same `predict(..., type = 'response')`

Comment: Assuming I'm on the right track here, you should clean up your question.  Then I'll clean up my answer.

Comment: Thanks Brian , I fixed my code. You are spot on my question. Is there are a way to get 95% CI for predict function?

Comment: You can do predict(...se.fit = TRUE) which returns a 2-element list. $fit and $se.fit.  Confidence intervals can be derived from there.  You want to use the untransformed, log-odds to set the CI.  Then transform if you need p.  Otherwise CI for p will be symmetric and that's wrong.

Comment: There's some good discussion here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/confidence-interval-for-gam-model